# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, github, dart

pasé mi aplicación a GitHub, le cambié el nombre y varias cosas mas, a la hora de querer ejecutarlo desde GitHub me da un error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Unable to delete file 'C:\Users\Tomas\Documents\GitHub\tramipet\build\app\intermediates\merged_res_blame_folder\debug\out'

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 4m 31s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
> Exited (sigterm)

Puede ser que cambié el nombre de la carpeta y ahí pasa este error?
O puede ser que al cambiarle el nombre a la carpeta, también le tengo que cambiar el nombre a todos los imports y al archivo .iml